# Entering a non-rooted, USB debugging OFF Android Device from PC

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

My friend cracked his display, and needs his IMEI number. He can't use his phone at all, so he can't turn on USB debugging from the device. Also, it is not rooted.

He never made (or doesn't remember) a Google-account on his Oneplus X, so he can't check his IMEI from the dashboard by Google.

Is it still possible to take over his phone from the PC, and dial-up the IMEI number on screen? His display still works, but not the touchscreen.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for **specific programming questions only**

Answer (score 1):

Each device has a recovery or fastboot mode, which normally can be used with only hardware buttons. Most devices display the IMEI there.